# Return Only Rows where count >= 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

This is my data set-up, I am needing a way to return only itemsnames and itemonhand where the count of itemonhand is >= 1

I tried simply adding an `OR` statement to the query, but that is returning items that have a 0 count.

```
  Declare @TableTest Table (dealerID int, itemname varchar(100), itemonhand int, itemname2 varchar(100), itemonhand2 int, itemname3 varchar(100), itemonhand3 int)
  INSERT INTO @TableTest (dealerID, itemname, itemonhand, itemname2, itemonhand2, itemname3, itemonhand3) VALUES
  (1, 'ball', 0, 'hat', 1, 'sock', 0)
  ,(2, 'ball', 0, 'hat', 0, 'sock', 1)

  Select * FROM @TableTest
  where itemonhand2 = '1'
  OR itemonhand3 = '1'
```

My desired result set is

```
1  hat  1
2  sock 1
```

I just want one row for each dealerID with all items returned on that one row.

Comment: Is redesigning the table on option? This would be much easier with only 3 columns (dealerID, itemName, itemOnHand)

Comment: @tper - yes a redesign is an option.  In my desired output I need only one row returned per dealerID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns your results and is more extensible for more items. It has been edited to return multiple items per dealer.

```
DECLARE @TableTest Table (dealerID int, itemname varchar(100), itemonhand int)
INSERT INTO @TableTest (dealerID, itemname, itemonhand) VALUES
(1,'ball',0),
(1,'hat',1),
(1,'sock',0),
(1,'bees',1),
(2,'ball',0),
(2,'hat',0),
(2,'sock',1);


SELECT dealerID,
stock = STUFF (
            (SELECT ',' + itemname  FROM @TableTest as t1 WHERE t1.itemonhand = 1 and t1.dealerID = t2.dealerID FOR XML PATH ('')), 1,1, '' 
            )
FROM @TableTest as t2
GROUP BY dealerID
```

Comment: How would I return only one row per dealerID if the DDL has a case where a dealerID has multiple itemsonhand?  Like if this was thrown into the DDL  (1,'bees', 1),

Comment: How would you like to determine which row to return for dealerID = 1 if they have both bees and hat with itemsonhand = 1? Are bees more important than hats?

Comment: They are both equally important.  I just want one row for each dealerID with all items returned on that one row.

Comment: Got it. Does the edited example using STUFF work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Live by the cross apply, die by the cross apply

```
 CREATE TABLE #TableTest
 (
   dealerID INT,
   itemname VARCHAR(100),
   itemonhand INT,
   itemname2 VARCHAR(100),
   itemonhand2 INT,
   itemname3 VARCHAR(100),
   itemonhand3 INT
 );
 INSERT INTO #TableTest
        ( dealerID, itemname, itemonhand, itemname2, itemonhand2, itemname3, itemonhand3 )
 VALUES ( 1, 'ball', 0, 'hat', 1, 'sock', 0 )
  ,     ( 2, 'ball', 0, 'hat', 0, 'sock', 1 );


 SELECT tt.dealerID,
        ca.*
 FROM   #TableTest AS tt
 CROSS APPLY ( SELECT   *
               FROM     ( VALUES ( itemname, itemonhand), ( itemname2, itemonhand2), ( itemname3, itemonhand3) ) x ( item_name, item_count ) ) ca
 WHERE  ca.item_count = 1;
```